# kubelet not deleting old containers

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I'm running the kubelet 1.5.4 and finding that even when I run low on disk space it will not delete old containers.

I have may exited containers, over an hour hold:

`$ sudo docker ps -a | grep 'Exited (0) About an hour' | wc -l
78`

But the kubelet does not seem to notice them (using a log level of 10 I see no references in kubelet logs to the container IDs).

Is this something that has changed recently? My previous 1.2 setup seemed to GC old containers.

Answer (score -2):

Kubelet has a feature to gc *images* but not sure what you mean by gc'ing containers?

See the proposal spec [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/kubelet-eviction.md#deprecation-of-existing-features) (it does seem as if it's due to be deprecated as well)

Comment: It's supposed to do both: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/garbage-collection/. Containers take up disk space and must be GC'd as well as images.